# RAILS 5: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem “actionpack”:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could anyone please help me for upgrading the rails 4.2 to rails 5.1.4
after run the bundle update got the compatible versions error

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_link_to (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
      actionpack

```
active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.6) was resolved to 0.10.7, which depends on
  actionpack (< 6, >= 4.1)

hamlit-rails (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

meta-tags (~> 2.4.1) was resolved to 2.4.1, which depends on
  actionpack (< 5.2, >= 3.2.0)

rails (~> 5.1.4) was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.4)

ransack (~> 1.6.6) was resolved to 1.6.6, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.0)

rspec-rails (~> 3.4.2) was resolved to 3.4.2, which depends on
  actionpack (< 4.3, >= 3.0)

simple_form (~> 3.5.1) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
  actionpack (< 5.2, > 4)

stream_rails (>= 2.5.2, ~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.6.1, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.0.0)

twitter-typeahead-rails (~> 0.10.5) was resolved to 0.10.5, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.1)
```

Comment: If you post your Gemfile & Gemfile.lock this would be easier to help debug. (If you're pointing to any gems/code from private repos make sure you remove the username/password from the appropriate fields)

Answer (score 10):

your rspec-rails blocks the upgrade. That bundler output shows this part:

```
actionpack (< 4.3, >= 3.0)
```

So rspec-rails blocks anything bigger that 4.2.

Release the rspec-rails contraint `~> 3.4.2` to something more relaxed like `~> 3.5` and try again

```
bundle update rails rspec-rails
```

In general, when upgrading Rails, try `bundle update rails` together with all the Gems that have specific version requirements for Rails or that are mentioned from bundler.

Comment: Already tried `bundle update rails` but getting same error and thanks for reply

Comment: Did you try ``bundle update rails rspec-rails``?
Did you try to remove the "~> 3.4.2" from the gem "rspec-rails" in your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and also removed '3.4.2' version from the gemfile but nothing get help

Comment: ... did the output of the bundle update ... change? Can you update your question with the new output?

Answer (score 2):

Remove your `Gemfile.lock` and add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

and don't forget to update your other gems.

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me when I was trying to update to rails 6. here is my workaround.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'


gem 'rails', '6.0.0.rc1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', platforms: [:jruby]
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'bootsnap'
gem "rspec"


group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

platforms :rbx do
  gem 'rubysl', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rubinius-developer_tools'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue when I used these gems with versions:

- gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4.2'
- gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7.0'

It worked for me after **removing gem version from specified gem**.

- gem 'rspec-rails'
- gem 'factory_girl_rails'